# How to fix "Broad Host Permissions" issue for publishing chrome plugin

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I am getting following error while publishing chrome plugin:

> `Broad Host Permissions`
>   Instead of requesting broad host permissions, consider using the activeTab permission, or specify the sites that your extension needs access to. Both options are more secure than allowing full access to an indeterminate number of sites, and they may help minimize review times.

Following is my `manifest.json` file content:

```
{
  "name": "Image listing",
  "version": "0.8",
  "description": "View all images",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
      "js": ["content.js"]
    }
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Image viewer",
    "default_icons": {
      "16": "images/16.png",
      "32": "images/32.png",
      "48": "images/64.png",
      "128": "images/128.png"
    }
  },
  "icons": {
    "16": "images/16.png",
    "32": "images/32.png",
    "48": "images/64.png",
    "128": "images/128.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

I am not using any `permission` property here, and I want my plugin to work in every site.

I have checked this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52929477/broad-host-permissions-webstore-warning-despite-only-one-host-in-permissions) as well,

> Having a host match in content scripts implicitly grants you host permissions.

but not able to figure out the solution for my issue.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Your content scripts run everywhere so your extension can access any site's data that's open in a tab.

Comment: @wOxxOm Yes, I want extension to be like that. A generic one , so that any one can use it.

Comment: Depending on what your extension does you'll have to live with that or switch to [activeTab model](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab) or use [optional permissions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/permissions).

Comment: @wOxxOm Let me try with optional permission option. Thanks